# How to get error value from a subscribed RACSignal?

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

For example:

In one controller, implementation

```
func sendSuccessOrNot()->RACSignal {
// code here
}
```

In another controller, calling that signal

```
controller.sendSuccessOrNot().subscribeNext {

}
```

how to check in the above calling if sendSuccessOrNot is sending error or success value in ReactiveCocoa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you use makes me think you're using Swift, in which case you shouldn't be using RACSignal, you should be converting your RACSignal to a SignalProducer with `.toSignalProducer()`

```
func sendSuccessOrNot() -> RACSignal {
    return RACSignal.createSignal { (subscriber) -> RACDisposable! in
        let test = true
        if (test) {
            subscriber.sendNext("Value")
            subscriber.sendCompleted()
        } else {
            subscriber.sendError(NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: nil))
        }
        return RACDisposable(block: {})
    }
}

controller.sendSuccessOrNot().toSignalProducer().on(next: { value in
    print("next: \(value)")
}, 
failed: { error in
    print("failed: \(error)")
}).start()
```

If you're still using RAC 2 then it'd be

```
controller.sendSuccessOrNot().subscribeNext({ value in
    print("next: \(value)")
}, error: { error in
    print("failed: \(error)")
})
```

Comment: do you know how to do in RAC 2.5 version or 2 version ?

Comment: RAC 2 but in Swift?

Comment: oh yes. I am doing RAC in swift and also to test it I want to send error from the function so how do I send error deliberately.

Comment: Edited to add the RAC 2 equivalent, but you should probably be using RAC 4.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I send error signal deliberately from the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112974/discussion-between-coolly-and-acid-burn).